# SQLite Asp.net 5 on Docker Ubuntu unable to connect db file, how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, sqlite, ubuntu

Good morning,
I developed an Asp.net 5.0 web app via VS Code on Mac OS Big Sur and then moved the app to Ubuntu server and recompiled to make it work in docker only it doesn't connect to the SQLite db file, how do I fix it?

The error is this:

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the connection string if this always occurs.  If it is a random failure than the connection did not complete the one time the error occurred.

Comment: @jdweng This is the complete error: https://pastebin.com/ZX49Pkre

Comment: I'm blocked right now from seeing the pastebin.  It appears that the path to the database file is wrong or another user/app is already opened the file or you do not have the permission to open the file.  You have to start by looking at the connection string.

Comment: i tried to give all permissions to the file and i tried to give all the file path address but no same error

Comment: Here are the valid connection string options : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: the string i use works on both mac os and windows 10 so the problem is docker or ubuntu.

The string I use is this: Data Source=Data/d-c.db

Comment: The driver may be issue.  What driver are you using?  See my last link which has list of drivers.  Is there any password on db file?